# Is there a way to force entry of a WPF DataGrid column before other columns?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have an editable DataGrid with a column A and B.  When adding a new item/row, it doesn't make sense for the user to enter anything in column B until they enter something in column A.  Is there a way to force the user, when creating a new item, to initialize column A first?  I'm able to use RowValidationRules just fine to ensure column A is initialized, but I'm trying to find a way to prevent that altogether.

I've also looked at handling Begin/Prepare cell edit events and cancelling edit of column B until A is initialized.  The problem there is that the user can enter a value for A but it is not yet visible/pending, and has not yet been committed by the DataGrid.

Comment: Are you using MVVM? Do you manage your Logic in CodeBehind? Why not make Column B readonly as long as Column a is invalid? Questions over questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this is your model

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _desc;
    public string Desc { get { return _desc; } set { _desc = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Desc"); } }

    string _name;
    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Name"); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void RaisePropertyChanged(string propname)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
    }
}
```

and first column is bound to `Name` and second column to `Desc`:

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="A" Binding="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="B" Binding="{Binding Desc}"/>
 </DataGrid.Columns>
```

you can handle `BeginningEdit` event, as you said. Note that in Binding the first column I set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`. This solve the issue you pointed out:

> it is not yet visible/pending, and has not yet been committed by the DataGrid

Now you can check the requirements and Cancel them if needed. For example:

```
    private void dg_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((DataGrid)sender).CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex == 1 && 
             ((Model)e.Row.Item).Name == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Insert value of the first column first!");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a `DataGridTemplateColumn` for Column B.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ColPropertyB}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ColPropertyB}"
                     IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=ColPropertyA, Converter={StaticResource IsPropertyInvalidConverter}}"  />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Instead of using the `IsReadOnly` property you could also use `Visibility` and multiple `UIElements` or what ever you want.

A second solution could be the usage of a `CellEditingTemplateSelector` and two `CellEdititingTempates`. The first with `TextBlock` if ColA is invalid and a `TextBox` otherwise. The `TemplateSelector` validates property `A` and returns the correct Template.

```
<!-- DataGrid ResourceDictionary -->
<DataTemplate x:Key="ValidTemplate">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ColPropertyB}" />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="InvalidTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ColPropertyB}" />
</DataTemplate>
<ColBTemplateSelector x:Key="ColBTemplateSelector"
        ValidDataTemplate="{StaticResource ValidTemplate}"
        InvalidDataTemplate="{StaticResource InvalidTemplate}" />

<!-- DataGridColumns -->
<DataGridTemplateColumn CellEditingTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ColBTemplateSelector}">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=RowPropertyB}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

TemplateSelector

```
public class ColBTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ValidDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate InvalidDataTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var tempItem = (item as YourDataItem);
        if (tempItem == null || tempItem.IsColPropertyAInvalid()) return InvalidDataTemplate;
        return ValidDataTemplate;
    }
}
```

With the `TemplateSelector` I'm not sure if it is called always when entering editing mode...

Comment: I like the first solution, but I'm not sure how to bind IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=ColPropertyA...".  You need a relative source.

Comment: You can bind it as it is written. The `DataContext` of the columns is the item and you can bind to each property. The validation is done at the `IsPropertyInvalidConverter`. The Converter needs to return `boolean` if valid or not...